# Selecting Multiple Dates in Calendar

Tags: ios, calendar

I am following [This Blog](http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=244) to add a calendar component in my application. Now I want to select more than one dates to show some report for selected dates.
How can I do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose in this tutorial tappedTile method is use for selection of date.so for selecting a number of dates you need to make array and add all the strings.

use like this

```
NSMutableArray *eventArray//your array for adding dates,make it propeerty and alloc it.

- (void)calendarView:(KLCalendarView *)calendarView tappedTile:(KLTile *)aTile{

      int month;
    month=[aTile.date monthOfYear];
    int day;
    day=[aTile.date dayOfMonth];
    int year=[aTile.date yearOfCommonEra];
    NSString *dateForCompare;

        dateForCompare=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i/%i/%i",month,day,year];


   [eventArray addObject:dateForCompare];
  //use this array (having dates in string format).
  // use this by using your logical capability 

}
```

see this [link](http://iphoneblog-ishu.blogspot.com/2011/02/many-time-your-app-needs-calender-which.html),may be it helps you

Comment: Thanks Ishu , but I am unable to catch more than one date by changing tappedTile method. Please help me out.

Comment: what do you mean by changing tappedTile

Comment: I just want to get the multiple dates in an array or string.

Because I want to pass the dates as a parameter and fetch some data from database. but here when I click on a Tile , one date is coming in console. I want to give the facility of selecting multiple dates to user and show the reports of all the dates selected. Help Needed

Comment: according to me my concept is right,but you need to check for when user tap twice then you need to remove the object from the array.

Comment: given in answer,it makes an array of dates when you tap on a tile.

Comment: Will try the whole code again. Thanks , Will contact you soon. Can you give me your gmail id ?

Comment: this is not right place to give my id,but you can again ask in same thread then we can chat in chat room.if this answer solves your problem then it needs acceptance of answer.